# calculating moving sum in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I want to find the running sum of a variable in a data table `dt`in R and want to return the month where this running sum is greater than or equal to a threshold which is mentioned in another column for that group,

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(pno = c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B", "B", "C", "C" ), 
                 month = c("Jan","Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun","Jul", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Mar", "Apr"),
                 x = c(1,2,1,3,2,4,1,3,4,2,4,2),
                 min_x_reqd = c(5,5,5,5,5,5,5,3,3,3,4,4),
                 min_mon = c(4,4,4,4,4,4,4,3,3,3,2,2))
```

the data.table `dt` looks like:

```
dt
    pno month x min_x_reqd min_mon
 1:   A   Jan 1          5       4
 2:   A   Feb 2          5       4
 3:   A   Mar 1          5       4
 4:   A   Apr 3          5       4
 5:   A   May 2          5       4
 6:   A   Jun 4          5       4
 7:   A   Jul 1          5       4
 8:   B   Jun 3          3       3
 9:   B   Jul 4          3       3
10:   B   Aug 2          3       3
11:   C   Mar 4          4       2
12:   C   Apr 2          4       2
```

For example: as per the data above, I want to calculate the sum of `x` for each `pno` for a moving window which is mentioned in `min_mon`. so at any time when this sum is greater than or equal to the threshold, which is mentioned in `min_x_reqd`, I want to return the first month for that window, in which it is satisfying the condition.

so in our case, as per the data, my output should be:

```
pno    month
A    Jan
B    Jun
C    Mar
```

how can I do this with either data.table/dataframe.

Answer (score 2):

We can do this with `roll_sum` from `RcppRoll` to calculate the rolling sum, then based on the logical condition, subset the first 'month' that satisfy the condition for each 'pno'

```
library(RcppRoll)
library(data.table)
dt[, .(month = month[which(roll_sum(x, min_mon[1], 
             fill = 0, align = "left") > min_x_reqd)[1]]), by = pno]
#   pno month
#1:   A   Jan
#2:   B   Jun
#3:   C   Mar
```

Comment: is there any other way than using the roll_sum function from RcppRoll library ?

Comment: @Archit You can use `rollsum` from `zoo`